# Tika - Is it possible to get the id attribute of a div tag?

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, apache-tika

Is it possible to filter what tika parses by the id attribute of div tags in the html?

I am trying to filter out divs with the id "header" because all the pages i am parsing have the same header and I only need the unique data.

I have already triggered the ContentHandler.StartElement for the div tags:

```
class MyHtmlMapper extends DefaultHtmlMapper {
    public String mapSafeElement(String name) {
        if ("DIV".equals(name)) {
            return "div";
        }
        return super.mapSafeElement(name);
    }
}
```

And I create the parser with the following:

```
InputStream urlInput = new URL(url).openStream();
Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
context.set(HtmlMapper.class, new MyHtmlMapper());
```

So I am assuming I have to override the BodyContentHandler.startElement() and BodyContentHandler.endElement() methods in the data handler (Something like the following):

```
class MyContnentHandler extends BodyContentHandler{
    public void startElement(String uri, String name, String element, Attributes atri) {
        ... 
        super.startElement(...)
    }
    public void endElement(...)
        ... //Similar to above
    }
}
```

I've been working on this for a little while and I'm just not terribly familiar with tika. If anyone has any suggestions or solutions they'd be greatly apprecieated!

I later learned that I could make the  attributes (i.e. id and class) show up in startElement by overriding the mapSafeAttribute method in the MyHtmlMapper class as follows:

```
class MyHtmlMapper extends DefaultHtmlMapper {
    public String mapSafeElement(String name) {
        if ("DIV".equals(name)) {
            return "div";
        }
        return super.mapSafeElement(name);
    }

    public String mapSafeAttribute(String eleName, String attrName) {
        HashSet<String> safeAttrs = new HashSet<String>();
        safeAttrs.add("id");
        safeAttrs.add("class");
        if (safeAttrs.contains(attrName) && eleName.equals("div")) {
            return attrName;
        } else {
            return super.mapSafeAttribute(eleName, attrName);
        }
    }
}
```

But I still cannot figure out how to stop the parser from parsing up the things in-between the start and end tag of the  with a given attribute property.

Let me know if I've left out any information that would be useful.

Comment: You don't need to include signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyHtmlMapper extends DefaultHtmlMapper {

    public public boolean isDiscardElement(String name) {
        //put here not wanted attributes
        HashSet<String> discardAttrs = new HashSet<String>();

        if (discardAttrs.contains(name) && eleName.equals("div")) {
            return true;
        } 
        return false;  
    }
)
```

http://tika.apache.org/1.2/api/index.html?org/apache/tika/parser/html/HtmlParser.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please explain why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: I thought that the code was clear, since Bacaa14 explained it and I have just extended that case. I posted also the link to javadoc where the method "isDiscardElement" is explained: "Checks whether all content within the given HTML element should be discarded instead of including it in the parse output. Subclasses can override this method to customize the set of discarded elements."

Comment: I've just read in Tika javadoc, that method isDiscardElement is deprecated, HTMLParser class should be used instead: http://tika.apache.org/1.2/api/index.html?org/apache/tika/parser/html/HtmlParser.html

Comment: You may add this to your post by editing it. You can always edit your own posts.